# Bootstrap 3 Overlap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 and would like these two grids I'm using in the JS Fiddle demo below to stack on top of each other instead of overlapping. The

> ```
> <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
> ```

overlaps over

> ```
> <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
> ```

I just need them to stack over each other so the ""nav nav-pills nav-stacked" isn't hidden.

[JS Fiddle example demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KCnJg/2/)

Here is the HTML Code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="max-width: 300px; background-color: #fff;">
                <li class="active"> <a href="#">link1</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">link2</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">link3</a>

                </li>
                <li> <a href="#">link4</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
            <div class="Rectangle_3_copy_2">
                <div class="Rounded_Rectangle_2"></div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want it to stack? From the bootstrap docs.

> Don't want your columns to simply stack in smaller devices? Use the extra small and medium device grid classes by adding .col-xs-* .col-md-* to your columns. See the example below for a better idea of how it all works.

So if you remove `col-xs-*` then it will stack.

[Bootply Demo](http://bootply.com/78730#)

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/KCnJg/4/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" style="max-width: 300px; background-color: #fff;">
            <li class="active"> <a href="#">link1</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">link2</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">link3</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">link4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="row">       
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
        <div class="Rectangle_3_copy_2">
            <div class="Rounded_Rectangle_2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```